# Toggle a website's color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm currently using a design that I made using the following tutorial to have both a black/white background on my website:

http://designshack.net/articles/css/lightsoff/

While this tutorial somewhat gets the job done (very sensitive to altering pieces of html/css around), I'm really looking for a much more elegant implementation. Is there any way to create a toggle'd switch using jquery or javascript that allows for changing the background color of an entire website?

I just picked up web programming as a hobby about a week ago so I know very little about javascript and jquery right now.

EDIT: I have a static site and I'm not too concerned on performance since the only person looking at this website 99.9% of the time will be me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write  this in javascript

```
var i=1;
function myFun()
{
if(i%2==0)
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";
else
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="white";

i++;
}
```

in event of click

```
<button onclick="myFun()">Click me</button>
```

I hope you got your ans. :)

Comment: Do I need to add any CSS or does <button onclick="... create a button when using javascript? I currently have a button I created using CSS from the guide that I posted in my original post, however I'm not sure if using javascript would create its own button or not

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate css file with styles defined for all the required elements in the page, and then add the css dynamically to the page based on the button click, or a radio select as shown below.

`$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" type="text/css" />');`

and

`$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');`

Here is a nice tutorial, which explains it

http://www.rickardnilsson.net/post/Applying-stylesheets-dynamically-with-jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Code your website using whatever you prefer as the default color scheme. Then, create css for alternate color schemes that are under a theme subclass. For instance:

```
p,h1 {color:red;]
.blue-theme p,h1 {color:blue;}
```

Then just use javascript or server-side variables to add the "blue-theme" class to your body or root element tag. This also makes it easy to transition between themes if you apply a css transition!

It's not the most efficient in terms of load sizes, as your CSS file will be slightly larger, and performance is not optimal as adding a theme will cost processing time, but for general use I believe it's the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is great for helping beginners add this type of functionality to websites. First, setup your CSS similar to this:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}

body.dark {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

This sets the default css to white, and then using JavaScript you'll add a "click handler" to you button by referencing the buttons id attribute to change the class (and resulting color):

```
$('#yourButtonID').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('dark');
});
```

You'll want to make sure you include a copy of jQuery in a  tag before you execute the above code on the page.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
```

Using jQuery for just this single application might be overkill, but it is the easiest way to accomplish what you want without experience and it's a library you can do a lot more with if you dive deeper into it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you the exactly code but definately look into some of the updating functions of javascript and implement css. Maybe load different css files as colors themes for your website.